# MySQL 5.6 service not going to stop

Tags: innodb, mysql-5.6

Something happennig in my environment

- MySQL 5.6.34
- RHEL 6
- 22G buffer pool size

When i stop MySQL it shows:

```
service mysql stop
.....................................
```

Until and unless I kill using `kill -9 <pid of mysqld_safe>`

Post killing when I start service `mysql`, it will start within 10 second....

But when I stop it, It will wait until an unless I kill the pid of mysql

What should I do...?

Comment: Could you share the command , from which command you are going to stop the mysql server?

Comment: service mysql stop command I used to stop mysql service

Comment: If this happens, first do, `SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST` to see if anything is still running.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue might be happening due to `innodb_max_dirty_pages_pct` and `innodb_log_buffer_size` as before shutdown Innodb needs to flush all the dirty buffers. It depends on the buffer pool size that how much dirty buffers are there.

You can check the link https://www.percona.com/blog/2010/09/02/how-long-innodb-shutdown-may-take for more detail.

In order to reduce the time, you can tune some mysql settings as mentioned in the blog https://www.percona.com/blog/2009/04/15/how-to-decrease-innodb-shutdown-times/